# What is this variable connecting with when I don't even have a class with that name

Tags: javascript

The variable called dots is connected with a document class called "dot", the problem is I don't have any class in my html that has the name of dot, I was working on a slider and used a lot of code from other people mish mashing it together while trimming everything I didn't need to get a extremely basic code, but as I was trying to understand what everything did this variable called dots is confusing me as it is necessary to make the slider even though there is no class called "dot" to necessitate it.

I am completely new to javascript, so I am sorry if I am asking something incredibly basic here but could someone please explain to me what is going on here.

this is the script.

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i = 0;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: since you haven't posted the html, I can't answer much. Looking at the JS code it, makes the dot as active (Apply an active style). So it should be a dot controller to move to the corresponding slide .Usually dots are placed right below the slider. 3 dots means there are 3 slides and you can click on any dot to move to that corresponding slide. Please check https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ to see the dots. In your case probably someone removed the dots

Comment: ohhhh, I see, so does this mean I can just remove the dots variable and replace all code with the name dot with slides instead? Nvm actually I just did that and it works perfectly! Thank you so much !